# Subset DataTable based on Numeric Values in Columns

Tags: r, subset

this is my first stack overflow post so please bear with me...

I wish to subset a datatable in R so that only rows containing digits are included - and rows containing characters are excluded. For example the table

```
 Date   Temperature
    41941.6656  1921
    41941.6656  1921
    41941.66561 1921
    41941.66563 1921
    41941.66564 1921
    41941.pypito    1921
    41941.66566 xWRET
    41941.66567 1921
```

should become

```
Date    Temperature
41941.6656  1921
41941.6656  1921
41941.66561 1921
41941.66563 1921
41941.66564 1921
41941.66567 1921
```

where xWRET represents some random character string that my stupid instrument often

I have tried    `is.numeric()` and    `grep()` however I cant get either to work.

I feel this should be very straightforward!

Thanks!

Comment: is Date Column to be considered numeric?

Comment: Yes - I can convert the date easily enough. however I thought I first needed to clear out all character entries as these shouldnt be there!

Comment: If `dt` is your `data.table`, you can try `dt[!(grepl("[a-zA-Z]",Date) | grepl("[a-zA-Z]",Temperature)),]`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can `dt[]<-na.omit(lapply(dt,as.numeric))` with the added benefit to have everything converted to numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the more general and efficient usage of `data.table` would be using `.SD` and `lapply` (in case you want to convert more than just two columns and you don't want to specify them manually)

Either

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))])
#        Date Temperature
# 1: 41941.67        1921
# 2: 41941.67        1921
# 3: 41941.67        1921
# 4: 41941.67        1921
# 5: 41941.67        1921
# 6: 41941.67        1921
```

Or

```
setDT(df)[, names(df) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))][complete.cases(df)]
#        Date Temperature
# 1: 41941.67        1921
# 2: 41941.67        1921
# 3: 41941.67        1921
# 4: 41941.67        1921
# 5: 41941.67        1921
# 6: 41941.67        1921
```

Answer (score 2):

If one is not yet familiar with [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) and the relative complexity its idiom, you could use base functions as well.

Assuming you are getting your data.frame columns as character.

```
df$Date <- as.numeric(df$Date)
df$Temperature <- as.numeric(df$Temperature)
```

or

```
df1 <- sapply(df, as.numeric)
```

and finally

```
df[complete.cases(df), ]
df1[complete.cases(df1), ]
```

to get

```
         Date Temperature
[1,] 41941.67        1921
[2,] 41941.67        1921
[3,] 41941.67        1921
[4,] 41941.67        1921
[5,] 41941.67        1921
[6,] 41941.67        1921
```

more on intro to `data.table` [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)

Comment: You are assuming here that the columns are of character type, right? Also, I'm not sure I've got your reference to `data.table`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for your comment. Yes, assuming char type and I've added the reference to `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly not the best way to do it, but here it goes:

```
library(data.table) # use this package, it is great for perfomance
lines="
41941.6656 1921
41941.6656 1921
41941.66561 1921
41941.66563 1921
41941.66564 1921
41941.pypito 1921
41941.66566 xWRET
41941.66567 1921"
con <- textConnection(lines)
d = data.table(read.table(con,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           sep=" ", 
           col.names=c("Date", "Temperature"), 
           fill=FALSE, 
           strip.white=TRUE))
close(con)
d<-d[!is.na(as.numeric(Temperature)) & !is.na(as.numeric(substr(Date,start=7,stop=7)))]
```

This to me, returns the following:

```
          Date Temperature
1:  41941.6656        1921
2:  41941.6656        1921
3: 41941.66561        1921
4: 41941.66563        1921
5: 41941.66564        1921
6: 41941.66567        1921
```

Is this what you want?